# collection view not working when app opens

Tags: iphone, ios7, uicollectionview

I have a tab bar app and the opening tab contains an almost full screen collection view with paging through images. When the app opens the paging doesn't work of is rough and sporadic, however, if you change tab and then return to the initial one the paging works absolutely fine.

Has anyone experienced this or know what could be causing this?

Here is the code used:

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createStoneData];
}

- (void)createStoneData {

    self.homeImages = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self.homeImages addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Biddlesdon Wardrobes", @"name",
                                @"_NP19981-Edit.jpg", @"image", nil]];
    etc….etc…etc….



    [self.collectionView reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.homeImages.count;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *homeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    homeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[self.homeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (_startingIndexPath) {
        NSInteger currentIndex = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - scrollView.bounds.size.width / 1) / scrollView.bounds.size.width) + 1;
        if (currentIndex < [self.homeImages count]) {
            self.title = self.homeImages[currentIndex][@"name"];
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Do you do anything in viewWIllAppear/viewWillDissapear ? Is it an iPad app ?

Comment: Does your image fetch takes long time?

Comment: Its a universal app with all images save in the app rather than on a database, I have added the code to the question so you can see what it does but like I say changing tab and returning it works without any problems.